# Online jQuery and json quiz, highlight correct answer

Tags: jquery, json

I´m making an online quiz. I took this code from http://www.flashbynight.com/tutes/mcqquiz/ I changed it and it is working fine.

When the user clicks on the right answer I managed to highlight it, but the trouble comes when I try to highlight the correct answer if the user has clicked in an incorrect answer.

Any ideas?

Thanks!!

```
$( document ).ready(function(){ 

  var myArr = [];
  var questionNumber=0;
  var questionBank=new Array();
  var stage="#game1";
  var stage2=new Object;
  var questionLock=false;
  var numberOfQuestions;
  var score=0;

  $.getJSON('preguntas.json', function(data) {

    for(i=0;i<data.quizlist.length;i++){ 
        questionBank[i]=new Array;
        questionBank[i][0]=data.quizlist[i].question;
        questionBank[i][1]=data.quizlist[i].option1;
        questionBank[i][2]=data.quizlist[i].option2;
        questionBank[i][3]=data.quizlist[i].option3;
        questionBank[i][4]=data.quizlist[i].option4;
    }
     numberOfQuestions=questionBank.length; 

    displayQuestion();
    })//gtjson

function displayQuestion(){
     var rnd=Math.random()*4;
     rnd=Math.ceil(rnd);
       var q1;
       var q2;
       var q3;
       var q4;

      if(rnd==1){q1=questionBank[questionNumber][1];q2=questionBank[questionNumber][2];q3=questionBank[questionNumber][3];q4=questionBank[questionNumber][4];}
      if(rnd==2){q2=questionBank[questionNumber][1];q3=questionBank[questionNumber][2];q4=questionBank[questionNumber][3];q1=questionBank[questionNumber][4];}
      if(rnd==3){q3=questionBank[questionNumber][1];q4=questionBank[questionNumber][2];q1=questionBank[questionNumber][3];q2=questionBank[questionNumber][4];}
      if(rnd==4){q4=questionBank[questionNumber][1];q1=questionBank[questionNumber][2];q2=questionBank[questionNumber][3];q3=questionBank[questionNumber][4];}

    $(stage).append('<div class="questionText">'+questionBank[questionNumber][0]+'</div><div id="1" class="option">'+q1+'</div><div id="2" class="option">'+q2+'</div><div id="3" class="option">'+q3+'</div><div id="4" class="option">'+q4+'</div>');



    $('.option').click(function(){ // when clicking on an answer

    $(this).css( "border", "3px solid #FC0");

     if(questionLock==false){questionLock=true; 

     //correct answer
     if(this.id==rnd){
        $(this).css( "border", "3px solid #FC0"); // I can highlight the answer when it is correct
      $(stage).append('<div class="feedback1">¡BIEN!</div>');
      score++;
      }

     //wrong answer 
    if(this.id!=rnd){
        $(stage).append('<div class="feedback2">UPS</div>');

       // I think I should put the code here, but I don´t know how to access the correct answer in order to highlight it 

     }

      setTimeout(function(){changeQuestion()},2000);
     }})
     }//display question

     function changeQuestion(){

    questionNumber++;

if(stage=="#game1"){stage2="#game1";stage="#game2";}
    else{stage2="#game2";stage="#game1";}

if(questionNumber<numberOfQuestions){displayQuestion();}else{displayFinalSlide();}


  $(stage2).animate({"right": "+=800px"},"fast", function() {$(stage2).css('right','-800px');$(stage2).empty();});
  $(stage2).hide();
  $(stage).show();
  $(stage).animate({"right": "+=800px"},"fast", function() {questionLock=false;});

}//change question



function displayFinalSlide(){

    $(stage).append('<div class="questionText">Felicidades, has terminado el cuestionario<br><br>Número de preguntas: '+numberOfQuestions+'<br>Respuestas correctas: '+score+'</div>');

}//display final slide

});
```

Comment: What exactly is `this.id` referring to? I don't see that property being added to the object anywhere?

Comment: @slime - `this.id` is the clicked `$('.option')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you give this a try?

From what I've gathered, `rnd` is the id of the correct answer, so by doing `$('#' + rnd)`, it should hopefully target the correct answer and apply the appropriate CSS.

```
if(this.id!=rnd){
    $(stage).append('<div class="feedback2">UPS</div>');

    // highlight correct answer
    $('#' + rnd).css( "border", "3px solid #FC0");

 }
```

The only drawback I see is that the answers have the same `id` in the different questions (or stages as they are described by the code) and `id`s should be unique so you might have to refactor a bit in order to make this valid.

If the `id`s were changed to a class then that would work better and I think you'd be able to do something like `$(stage + ' .option.' + class);` or `$(stage').find('.option.' + class);` where `class` is the number of the correct answer, `1`, `2` or `3` but you should be able to target the right answer for the specific question by doing `$(stage + ' #' + rnd);` aswell to make your intentions clearer even though it's still invalid.

Comment: OP You should really look into *why* this answer worked if you want to learn web programming.  If you don't understand this you will constantly get stuck.  It sounds like you are stumbling around in the dark a bit.

Comment: Yeah maybe you are right. Another thing: If I send myself the folder with all the files, why I can't open it right in Safari and Chrome and it only works with Firefox?

Comment: hmm....  I'm not really sure to be honest.  Try working in Visual Studio if  you aren't already and that's an option.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the html?  You need to use the id of the tag of the correct answer to select it and then highlight it using the same .css method.  You need:

```
$("#ID_of_Correct_Answer").css( "border", "3px solid #FC0");
```

This should be in the place you suspect it should go.  However, you need to ID of the HTML tag that holds the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just put this code to `incorrect answer`.It will work

```
if(this.id!=rnd){
   $(stage).append('<div class="clearfix"></div><div class="col-md-12 feedback2">WRONG ANSWER</div><div class="col-md-12 quiz-answer">Correct Answer is : '+questionBank[questionNumber][1]+'</div>');
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow..!!Consider formatting the answer from next time..!